# Is sin at laylatul Qadr multiplied by thousands of times?

Tags: sin, laylat-al-qadr

We all know that good and bad deeds are multiplied in the month of Ramadan. [This answer in islamqa.info](http://islamqa.info/en/38213), says similar thing that doing sin in the month of Ramadan is multiplied in terms of quality, and the punishment is more severe.

We also know that the night of Qadr is better than a 1000 months. Doing good deeds at that night is thousands of times better than doing good deeds at other nights. By the same logic, **is committing sin at the night of Qadr multiplied by some thousands of times?**

Answer (score 1):

Allah says in the Holy Quran:

[image]

> Whoever comes [on the Day of Judgement] with a good deed will have ten times the like thereof [to his credit], and whoever comes with an evil deed will not be recompensed except the like thereof; and they will not be wronged. [6:160]

Allah also says:

[image]

> Whoever does an evil deed will not be recompensed except by the like thereof; but whoever does righteousness, whether male or female, while he is a believer - those will enter Paradise, being given provision therein without account. [40:40]

Allah also says:

[image]

> Whoever comes [at Judgement] with a good deed will have better than it, and they, from the terror of that Day, will be safe. [27:89]

Allah also says:

[image]

> Whoever comes [on the Day of Judgement] with a good deed will have better than it; and whoever comes with an evil deed - then those who did evil deeds will not be recompensed except [as much as] what they used to do. [28:84]

As we can clearly see from these Ayat. A good deed will be multiplied, however, a bad deed will stay itself, just 1 bad deed regardless of where the person is or when it occurs. This is one of the mercies of Allah.

Some scholars use the following Ayah to say that Bad deeds in certain places are bad:

[image]

> Indeed, those who have disbelieved and avert [people] from the way of Allah and [from] al-Masjid al-Haram, which We made for the people - equal are the resident therein and one from outside; and [also] whoever intends [a deed] therein of deviation in religion - We will make him taste of a painful punishment.[22:25]

However, you can clearly see this Ayah speaking about the Quresh people who used to worship Idols at the Kabba, which this forbids it. It clearly says deviation in religion `الحاد` which translated to disbelieving. This Ayah mentions nothing about sins or wrongdoings.

> وَقَدْ رَوَى الْحَافِظُ أَبُو الْقَاسِمِ التَّمِيمِيُّ فِي التَّرْغِيبِ ثَنَا سُلَيْمَانُ بْنُ إبْرَاهِيمَ ثَنَا عَبْدُ اللَّهِ بْنُ مُحَمَّدِ ابْنِ حَمْدَيْهِ ثَنَا مُحَمَّدُ بْنُ عَبْدِ اللَّهِ بْنِ إبْرَاهِيمَ ثَنَا مُحَمَّدُ بْنُ أَحْمَدَ بْن أَبِي الْعَوَّامِ ثَنَا أَبُو خَلَفُ بْنُ خَلِيفَةَ عَنْ عَبْدِ اللَّهِ بْنِ عَبْدِ اللَّهِ بْنِ أَبِي مُلَيْكَةَ عَنْ الْأَعْمَش عَنْ أَبِي صَالِحٍ عَنْ أَبِي هُرَيْرَةَ مَرْفُوعًا فَذَكَرَهُ وَفِي آخِرِهِ { فَاتَّقُوا شَهْرَ رَمَضَانَ فَإِنَّ الْحَسَنَاتِ تُضَاعَفُ فِيهِ وَكَذَلِكَ السَّيِّئَاتُ } وَهُوَ خَبَرٌ ضَعِيفٌ .
>
> Narrated Alhafid Abu Kassim Altayami, .. (list of names of narrations) ... narrated from Abu Huriria at the end: "Beware of the month of Ramadan, that good and bad deeds are increased during it" - However, this was a very weak narration.

As we can clearly see from the first Ayah. Those who come with a Sin, they will only be judge on it.

Based on the above proofs, it means that the sin in The night of Qadr (and everywhere/everytime) is counted as 1 sin and not multiplied.

Comment: so, the answer is inconclusive?

Comment: @Mi_Onim I have posted a more correct approach to the question along with why it is not multiplied.

Comment: but [http://islamqa.info/en/38213] say that sins are multiplied in terms of quality i.e. punishment are more severe

Comment: Difference of opinions. At least my opinions are backed by the Quran, not my whims.

Comment: well, they answered it based on the opinion of _Scholar of the Umma_, Ibn Abbas (RA). Their opinion carries a lot of weight because of that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Laylatul Qadr one night is equivalent of 1000+ night. There a Sahih Hadith:

> The Messenger of Allah (صلى الله عليه و آله وسلم‎) was shown the lifespans of the people (who had gone) before him, or what Allah willed of that, and it was as if the lives of the people of his community had become too short for them to be able to do as many good actions as others before them had been able to do with their long lives, so Allah gave him Laylat al-Qadr, which is better than a thousand months.

[Sunan Ibn Majah 19.6.16]

**Thousand (1000) months is equivalent of:**

- Eighty three (83) years and four (4) months.
- Thirty thousand (30,000) days.
- Seven hundred twenty thousand (7,20,000) hours.
- It is longer than most of us whole life.